# Why does the EDF between a univariate GAM and multiple covariates in the GAM differ?

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

Below is my output for when `soil.loss ~ +s(ksoil) + s(porosity)`

```
              edf Ref.df     F  p-value    
s(ksoil)    3.832  3.832 19.40 1.22e-05 ***
s(porosity) 1.000  1.000 11.52  0.00499 **
```

Below is my output for each independent variable with response variable, 
when `soil.loss ~ s(porosity)`

```
              edf Ref.df     F p-value    
s(porosity) 2.899  2.899 130.5  <2e-16 ***
```

when soil.loss ~ s(ksoil)

```
           edf Ref.df     F p-value    
s(ksoil) 3.371  3.371 107.3  <2e-16 ***
```

Why does the EDF for porosity change from 2.899 into 1.00 , when the fitted model is combined?

Answer (score 1):

Because `ksoil` and `porosity` are not orthogonal to one another.

Note that the meaning of the effect of `ksoil` in model

```r
y ~ s(ksoil)
```

is very different to the meaning in model

```r
y ~ s(porosity) + s(ksoil)
```

In the second model you are looking at the partial effect of `ksoil` given the effect of `porosity`. In the first model, the `s(ksoil)` term is explaining some of the variation in the response that can be explained by `porosity`. Once you account for `ksoil` the effect of `porosity` is linear.

Comment: Are the variable names switched in your last sentence? (i.e. "linear" is `EDF = 1`)

Comment: @GeoMatt22 Yes they are; I'll fix that